# Spacing in list environments

Tags: spacing, koma-script

I don't understand the following spacing behavior:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% on/off
\setparsizes{0pt}{\smallskipamount plus 2pt}{0pt plus 1fil}
%

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item foo
        \item foo
        \item foo
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The modification of the paragraph formatting leads to different spacing in lists (smaller vertical space between items).

1. Where does this come from? I guess from some internal `\parskip` change...
2. How do I keep the default spacing?
3. Is it a bad idea to keep it?

Comment: \setparsizes is a KOMA command.  See page 457 of the KOMAscript manual.  IIRC, itemize does not change \parkskip, but simply adds things like \itemsep, plus the occasional \unskip.

Comment: I know it is a KOMA command. But I'm pretty sure it does change \parskip, because \parskip is responsible for the vertical space after paragraphs. In theory one could just change \parskip and \parindent, but that can lead to problems as some other values depend on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grabbed the values of `\parsep`, `\itemsep`, and `\topsep` with the option turned off.  Then, I used `enumitem` to reset those values manually.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% on/off
\setparsizes{0pt}{\smallskipamount plus 2pt}{0pt plus 1fil}
%

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}[parsep=4.5pt plus 2pt minus 1pt,
                    itemsep=4.5pt plus 2pt minus 1pt,
                    topsep=9pt plus 3pt minus 5pt]
        \item foo \the\parsep, \the\itemsep, \the\topsep
        \item foo
        \item foo
    \end{itemize}
Without reset
    \begin{itemize}
        \item foo \the\parsep, \the\itemsep, \the\topsep
        \item foo
        \item foo
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s.  I learned from the **parskip** package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) that these three *sep* values are the ones affected by changes in `\parskip`.

Comment: That's exactly how I would have approached it. Thanks so far. I wondered, if there was a more intrinsic KOMA script approach, but it doesn't seem so.